# SQL server recovery mechanism

Tags: c#, sql, service

I have a service application in C# which queries data from one database and inserts it into another SQL database.

Sometimes, the MSSQLSERVER service crashed for unknown reason and my application will crash as well. I want to do a SQL recovery mechanism that where I check to make sure the sqlconnection state is fine before i write to the database but how i do that?

I tried stopping MSSQLSERVER service and sqlconnection.State is always open even when the MSSQLSERVER service is stopped.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but this sounds a little amusing 'Sometimes, the MSSQLSERVER service crashed for unknown reason' :)

Comment: "Sometimes, the MSSQLSERVER service crashed for unknown reason " - it should never crash. When I say never, I mean NEVER!

Comment: It did! The service is stopped after running for several days. Any resolution? I need to do some checking in the code. Tried using the sqlconnection.State property but that's always OPEN.

Comment: Reinstall system, then if taht does not help check hardware. SQL Server DOES NOT CRASH.

Comment: @overrule: "The service is stopped after running for several days" - then you have a big problem. I've seen SQL Server instances up for a year (and only had to be restarted for an update).

Comment: @overrule: what do the SQL Server error logs say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the approach you chose is not very good.

If your application is some kind of scheduled job, let it crash. No database - no work can be done. This is ok to crash in this case. Next time it runs and db is up it will do its thing. You can also implement retries.

If your application is a windows service inside and some kind of scheduled timer, you just make sure that your service doesn't crash by handling SqlExcpetion. Retry again until server is up.

Also, you might want to use distributed transactions. To guarantee integrity of the copy procedure, but whether you need it or not, depends on the requirements.

**[Edit]** In response to retry question.

```
var attemptNumber = 0;
while (true)
{
    try
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();

            // do the job
        }
        break;
    }
    catch (SqlException exception)
    {
        // log exception
        attemptNumber++;
        if (attemptNumber > 3)
            throw; // let it crash
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do a retry but how do i check the SQLconnection is down ? THe State property always showing as OPEN eventhough the MSSQLSERVER service is down.

Comment: @overule - if you keep connection open, this is not good. I updated the answer with the retry approach.

Comment: I have to keep the connection open because the SQL data comes in a bit later and not instantly so I can't do a connect to database and disconnect straight away.

Comment: The code you gave does not work because the sql connection is opened once.

Comment: @overule - not sure I understand your scenario, but this is a bad approach to keep connection open. Instead you open connection when you need it and close as soon as possible. I would need to take a look at the code in order to provide more details.

Comment: Sometimes the SQL server will occasionally  be shutdown for patching or rebooted and the service is stopped so my code need to handle that. But there's no good way for me to determine if the SQL server is up or down.

Comment: @overule the good way to determine is to handle SqlExceptions. Got exception - something is wrong with SQL server.

Comment: Funny enough, there's no exception when the SQLSERVER is stopped. Just that no data is transferred.

Answer (score 1):

First: Fix your real problem. SQL Server should be very, very stable.

Second: consider using MSMQ (or SQL Service Broker) on both the client application and server to queue updates.

Comment: I need a way of checking SQLConnection state but the state always reflect the wrong status. I have to fix the code to make sure it's stable.

Comment: @overrule: fix your server, first.

Answer (score 1):

The general strategy of checking the connection state before calling a SQL command fundamentally won't work. What happens if the service crashes after your connection check, but before you call the SQL command?

You probably will need to figure out what exception is thrown when the database is down and recover from that exception at the appropriate layer of code.

Comment: It's hard to get SQL service to crash. I need to put in something in my code so it will not happen again.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint, stop the SQL service, then resume code execution to simulate a crash and find out what exception will be thrown.

Comment: Of, course, as others have said, it shouldn't be common for SQL service to crash. But being prepared for it being inaccessible (network problems, etc.) is a good idea and should probably be handled appropriately in your client application.